# Pandas. ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python

Please Help ! I have almost the same structure of SMA and EMA code. SMA code is OK, but EMA code gets an error: "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index."

SMA(simple moving average) code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
window_length = 20
df = pd.read_csv("TWII_2009-2011.csv")
df=df.set_index('Date')  #####
close = df['Close']
def simple_moving_average(window_length):
    sma=[]
    for i in range(len(close)):
        if i+1 < window_length:
            sma.append(0)
        else:
            sma.append(sum(close[i+1 - window_length : i+1])/window_length)
    return sma
df['SMA'] = simple_moving_average(window_length)
```

EMA(exponential moving average) code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
window_length = 20
df = pd.read_csv("TWII_2009-2011.csv")
df=df.set_index('Date')  #####
close = df['Close']
def exponential_moving_average(window_length):
    ema = []
    j=1
    for i in range(len(close)):
        if i+1 < window_length:
            sma = sum(close[:window_length]) / window_length
            multiplier = 2 / float(1 + window_length)
            ema.append(sma)
            ema.append(( (close[window_length] - sma) * multiplier) + sma)
        else:
            tmp = ( (i - ema[j]) * multiplier) + ema[j]
            j = j + 1
            ema.append(tmp)
    return ema
df['EMA'] = exponential_moving_average(window_length)
```

Comment: i formatted your code.  But in the future.. highlight your code and press the {} button on the edit ribbon.

Comment: Have you tried any debugging at all?

Comment: You should post the full traceback as this will identify exactly where the error is.

Comment: the error shows on this line "df['EMA'] = exponential_moving_average(window_length)"

Comment: @James, no, that's not where the problem is. Post the full traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/@@@pg/yahoo_final_Chang/PartsForCombining_Python/@@BOOK--EMA_22_ForLoop_Date_OneDiagram_Indicator.py", line 24, in <module>
    df['EMA'] = exponential_moving_average(...)

Comment: File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2299, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2366, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2524, in _sanitize_column
    value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)

Comment: File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2741, in _sanitize_index
    raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of '
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: @James: please add the traceback to your _question_, not as a comment - it's very difficult to read unformatted comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You append ema twice! in the first 'If' statement**   Whereas in SMA you append only once. Remove one..

```
for i in range(len(close)):
            if i+1 < window_length:
                sma = sum(close[:window_length]) / window_length
                multiplier = 2 / float(1 + window_length)
                ema.append(sma)
                ema.append(( (close[window_length] - sma) * multiplier) + sma)
            else:
                tmp = ( (i - ema[j]) * multiplier) + ema[j]
                j = j + 1
                ema.append(tmp)
        return ema
```

You should lookup pandas methods for these calculations.

Comment: I have tried either ema.append(sma) or ema.append(( (close[window_length] - sma) * multiplier) + sma).  the error is disappear, but the output is not an ema value. thanks anyway! I will try to lookup pandas methods for these calculations.